# Replacing multiple blanks in a sentence

Tags: c, string

I'm getting some character in the end. Although it doesn't happen all the time. Can someone please tell how to rectify the mistake?

```
main()
{      
    char ar[100];
    char br[100];
    gets(ar);
    int c=strlen(ar);
    int b=0,d=0;
    while(b<c)
    {
        br[d]=ar[b];
        if(ar[b]==' ')
        {
            while(ar[b]==' ')
            {
                b++;
            }
            b--;
        }
        b++;   
        d++;  
    }

    printf("\n");

    puts(br);  
    getch();         
}
```

Input:

```
Hello    this is vinay.
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello this is vinay.
```

Output which I'm getting:

```
Hello this is vinay.*
```

*`*` is some right arrow character not sure how to describe it.*

Comment: Please post a example of input, expected output and real output.

Comment: It seems to be the time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: You can reduce the number of indexes that you have to keep track of if you change this to only insert the character if it is not a space. Right now you insert it and then check if it's a space which makes it more complicated.

Comment: Add `br[d] = 0` after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to null terminate your string, so when printing the string, `printf` stop at the end of the memory instead of the end of the string, which for the user mean, print garbage, here the code corrected:

```
int main() //main is supposed to return a int
{      
    char ar[100];
    char br[100];
    gets(ar);
    int c=strlen(ar);
    int b=0,d=0;
    while(b<c)
    {
        br[d]=ar[b];
        if(ar[b]==' ')
        {
            while(ar[b]==' ')
            {
                b++;
            }
            b--;
        }
        b++;   
        d++;  
    }
    br[d] = '\0'; //null terminate the string. `br[d]=0;` work too.
    printf("\n");

    puts(br);  
    getch();     
    return 0; //Convention for "all is good"    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Error will be somwhere here..b++; b--; b++;

if(ar[b]==' ')
    {
        while(ar[b]==' ')
        {
            b++;
        }
        b--;
    }
    b++;
```

Comment: this is too vague to nail it.